# How to convert voltage (or frequency) floating number read backs to mV (or kHz)?

Tags: python, floating-point, number-formatting, pyvisa

I am successfully able to read back data from an instrument:

- When the read back is a voltage, I typically read back values such as `5.34e-02` Volts.
- When the read back is frequency, I typically read values like `2.95e+04`or `1.49e+05` with units Hz.

I would like to convert the voltage read back of `5.34e-02` to exponent e-3 (aka millivolts), ie.. `53.4e-3`. next, I would like to extract the mantissa `53.4` out of this because I want all my data needs to be in milliVolts.

Similarly, I would like to convert all the frequency such as `2.95e+04` (or `1.49e+05`) to kiloHz, ie... `29.5e+03` or `149e+03`. Next would like to extract the mantissa `29.5` and `149` from this since all my data needs to be kHz.

Can someone suggest how to do this?

Comment: What is type of your data?

Comment: the data is floating number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to convert volts to millivolts, you multiply by 1000.  To convert Hz to kHz, you divide by 1000.

```
>>> reading = 5.34e-02
>>> millivolts = reading * 1000
>>> print(millivolts)
53.400000000000006
>>> hz = 2.95e+04
>>> khz = hz /1000
>>> khz
29.5
>>>
```

### FOLLOW-UP

OK, assuming your real goal is to keep the units the same but adjust the exponent to a multiple of 3, see if this meets your needs.

```
def convert(val):
    if isinstance(val,int):
        return str(val)
    cvt = f"{val:3.2e}"
    if 'e' not in cvt:
        return cvt
    # a will be #.##
    # b will be -##
    a,b = cvt.split('e')
    exp = int(b)
    if exp % 3 == 0:
        return cvt
    if exp % 3 == 1:
        a = a[0]+a[2]+a[1]+a[3]
        exp = abs(exp-1)
        return f"{a}e{b[0]}{exp:02d}"
    a = a[0]+a[2]+a[3]+a[1]
    exp = abs(exp-2)
    return f"{a}e{b[0]}{exp:02d}"


for val in (5.34e-01, 2.95e+03, 5.34e-02, 2.95e+04, 5.34e-03, 2.95e+06):
    print( f"{val:3.2e} ->", convert(val) )
```

Output:

```
5.34e-01 -> 534.e-03
2.95e+03 -> 2.95e+03
5.34e-02 -> 53.4e-03
2.95e+04 -> 29.5e+03
5.34e-03 -> 5.34e-03
2.95e+06 -> 2.95e+06
```

Comment: Hi Tim, as simple as you make it sound, the intention of my question is really to convert 5.34e-2 to 53.4e-3 without changing the data by multiplying by 1000. Is there a more direct way to change e-2 to e-3 and then extract the mantissa of the resultant representation?

Comment: `5.34e-2` _is exactly the same as_ `53.4e-3`! The scientific format is defined as one number before the decimal point, and whatever exponent is needed to express it thus. `x.xxxe+/-x` If you want to _format_ your value as `something e-3` then you just need to divide by `1e-3` to find the mantissa, and then tack on `"e-3"` to that when you print it. Note that dividing by `1e-3` is the same as multiplying by `1000`, which is what Tim has done. What could be more direct than that? @Sinha

Comment: very wise response @PranavHosangadi . What about 75.1e-1 or 890.1e-7? would multiplying 1000 solve my problem? the data can be anything, not necessarily e-2 all the time! The answer I am looking for is if there is some python function to convert the floating number to e-3 exponent and then be able to extract the resultant mantissa... Just now came across frexp() trying to see how it works

Comment: You said you wanted millivolts.  5.34e-02 volts is 53.4 millivolts.  It's just that simple.  The hackery you're talking about (dropping the e-03) is accomplished by multiplying by 1000.  That's just the proper way to do what you're describing

Comment: @Sinha you're asking "how many millivolts are in `X` volts". The answer to that is _always_ `X * 1000`, because that's the conversion from volts to millivolts. It doesn't matter what `X` is, as long as the unit of `X` is volts.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi of course I am not seeking a forum such as stackoverflow to educate myself that conversion between V and mV is a 1000multiplier. I think you are jumping on too quick suggestions merely by reading the title and not understanding my eventual ask! To help put forward to you more explicitly: how do I convert 75.1e-1 or 890.1e-7 or 5.34e-2 to —-> 75100e-3, 0.00089e-3, 53.4e-3? That would be mV representation. I would strongly request you to not jump to judging the question than to provide constructive inputs, because it throws off other contributors to dismiss the question already.

Comment: @Sinha -- You should not criticize the commenters, because your spec is unclear.  You said you wanted millivolts.  We've provided that.  If you actually want volts, but with the number expressed in scientific notation with an exponent as a multiple of 3, then you need to say that.  And that's a conversion you need to do by hand.

Comment: got it, thanks for your inputs, will better rephrase next time. Ironically, I have been using phrases such as "request" and "please" in my comments as against, others' comments have reacted with "!" and judging tone insinuating how appaling my question is. Anyways, thank you for suggestion you all. Criticizing was never my intention. Any help is a blessing.

Comment: @Sinha I really didn't mean to be rude or put you down in any way with my previous comments, and I apologize if you perceived it that way. `75.1e-1` is just `7.51` volts, which is `7.51 * 1000 = 7510` _milli_ V, or `7510e-3` volts. Basically, `e-3` is a synonym for _milli_. `890.1e-7` volts is `0.00008901` volts, or `0.00008901 * 1000 = 0.08901` mV. This pattern doesn't change regardless of what the input is. The question one would ask to make this conversion is, given `X` volts, how many mV or `1e-3` volts fit in `X`? And the answer to that is `X / 1e-3`, or `X * 1000`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think multiplying/dividing by 1000 is enough to move between [SI prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix).  But when units get more complicated it might help to use a library like [Pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/) to keep track of things and make sure you're calculating what you think you are.

In this case you might do:

```
import pint

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
Q = ureg.Quantity

reading_v = Q(5.34e-02, 'volts')
reading_mv = reading_v.to('millivolts')

print(reading_mv.magnitude)
```

but it seems overkill here.